# Core Dumped al copiar dirección de puntero

Tags: c++, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

Al momento de asignar una direction de un puntero con memoria existente y funcional a otro puntero que apunta a nada **(nullptr)**, C++ me regresa:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

- Eh intentado asignar la memoria de **nnodo** como: `(struct linked_list*)(malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list)))`
- Eh comprobado y la copia de direcciones entre **first** y **temp** se realiza correctamente.

```
#define type int

struct node{
        // Nodo: con un valor numérico y un puntero al sig. nodo. 
        type value = 0;
        struct node *next = nullptr;
};
    
struct linked_list{
        struct node *first = nullptr;
        struct node *temp  = nullptr;
        
        void append(type value)
        {
            // Creación del nodo
            struct node *nnode = new node;
            nnode -> value = value;
            nnode -> next = nullptr;
           
            // Nuestro puntero temporal apunta al primer nodo conocido.
            temp = first;
            
            // Y viaja por cada nodo hasta llegar al final / ultimo nodo vació.
            while(temp != nullptr)
                 temp = temp -> next;
            
            // Una vez en el ultimo nodo (en blanco), 
            // este es reasignado con un nodo (dirección) funcional.
            temp = nnode; /*Error*/
        }
```

Comment: Debes cambiar "type" por un tipo valido en c++ como int, float, double

Comment: Disculpa que no lo añadí, pero tengo ```#define type int``` al inicio del documento*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nota inicial: En C++ no hace falta poner `struct` al declarar variables. Es preferible, por tanto hacer esto:

```
struct node{
    // Nodo: con un valor numérico y un puntero al sig. nodo. 
    type value = 0;
    node *next = nullptr;
};
```

a esto

```
struct node{
    // Nodo: con un valor numérico y un puntero al sig. nodo. 
    type value = 0;
    struct node *next = nullptr;
};
```

De la misma forma, para declarar tipos es preferible usar `typedef` o `using` a ese engendro del lenguaje llamado macro:

```
// C++03 y anteriores
typedef int type;

// C++11
using type = int;
```

Vale, y ahora vamos con tu problema.

```
// Y viaja por cada nodo hasta llegar al final / ultimo nodo vació.
while(temp != nullptr)
     temp = temp -> next;

// Una vez en el ultimo nodo (en blanco), 
// este es reasignado con un nodo (dirección) funcional.
temp = nnode; /*Error*/
```

La línea que marcas con el error, **no hace absolutamente nada**. No tiene ningún efecto sobre tu programa. Para entender el motivo hay que entender antes cómo funcionan los punteros.

Un puntero funciona prácticamente igual que una variable al uso. Es decir, ante una asignación, por ejemplo:

```
int* ptr1 = func();
int* ptr2 = ptr1;
```

Lo que se consigue es almacenar en `ptr2` el mismo valor que contiene `ptr1`. Como son punteros, los valores almacenados identifican posiciones de memoria, pero no hay que olvidar que no dejan de ser números.

Así, si `ptr1` almacenaba el valor `0x123`, `ptr2` acabará almacenando ese mismo valor. El efecto final será que ambos punteros apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria. Sin embargo no hay que perder de vista el hecho de que **son variables independientes**, si redireccionas uno de los dos punteros, el otro no sufrirá ningún cambio:

```
// A dónde apuntara ahora ptr1??
ptr2 = new int[40];
```

Tras esta otra línea que hemos añadido, `ptr1` seguirá apuntando a la posición de memoria `0x123`, es decir, `ptr1` no sufre cambios. De la misma manera, lo que hubiese en la posición de memoria `0x123` tampoco habrá sufrido cambios.

Dicho esto vamos a ver otra vez tu código:

```
// Y viaja por cada nodo hasta llegar al final / ultimo nodo vació.
while(temp != nullptr)
     temp = temp -> next;

// Una vez en el ultimo nodo (en blanco), 
// este es reasignado con un nodo (dirección) funcional.
temp = nnode; /*Error*/
```

En el bucle vas actulizando `temp` hasta que apunta a `nullptr`. Después reasignas `temp`. Entiendo que tu idea es colocar `nnode` al final de la lista, pero para eso tienes que modificar `temp->next` no `temp`. Claro está no puedes hacer `temp->next` si `temp==nullptr` ... el truco es dejar que `temp` se quede en el que será el penúltimo nodo:

```
// Y viaja por cada nodo hasta llegar al final / ultimo nodo vació.
while(temp->next != nullptr)
     temp = temp -> next;

// Una vez en el ultimo nodo (en blanco), 
// este es reasignado con un nodo (dirección) funcional.
temp->next = nnode;
```

Ahora si funcionará, ya que tu intención no es modificar `temp` sino `temp->next`, esto es , un puntero que pertenece a un nodo.

Por otro lado, piensa qué pasaría si la lista estuviese vacía, es decir que `first==nullptr`. Pista: El programa falla.

Este es un caso especial que debes tratar aparte. Lo primero que debes hacer es detectar esta situación y actuar en consecuencia actualizando `first`:

```
if( first == nullptr )
    first = nnode;
else
{
    // Añadimos el nodo al final de la vista
}
```

Dado que `first` es un puntero de tu clase, es decir, no es una variable temporal, este cambio hará que el primer elemento que añadas sea referenciado automáticamente por tu puntero `first`. En el resto de situaciones, el bucle que hemos arreglado se encargará de añadir el nodo al final de la lista.

Nota que no hay ninguna necesidad de declarar `temp` como variable miembro de la clase. Es una variable temporal y, como tal, su vida debería limitarse a la función `append`. Alargar innecesariamente la vida de las variables da más problemas que soluciones, tenlo en cuenta.